# Inverse of elementary row operation explanation

Tags: linear-algebra

In my textbook, the following is found (regarding the inverse of an elementary row operation):

"Type III - Adding $k$ times row $p$ to a different row $q$ is reversed by adding $-k$ times row $p$ to row $q$ (in the new matrix). Note that $p \ne q$ is essential here."

I don't see why $p$ cannot equal $q$. Even if the two rows are equal, if I add the row and then add its inverse it will reverse the operation. What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $r$ is your row, after adding it $k$ times to itself, you get $r+kr=(k+1)r$, which already changes it.

Trying to revert the operation will not give the original result. Subtracting $k$ times itself you get $(k+1)r-k(k+1)r=(k^2-1)r\ne r$

So it is essential that $p \ne q$